# Append CSV file to existing Access table

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database with a ton of tables, forms, and queries in it. With one of my forms I have an upload button that I would like to use for appending csv files to a specific table in the database.

I have an OnClick function for the button that I am getting hung up on..

Every time it get to the line

```
adoCSVConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strPathToTextfile & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
```

It says that: *the provider cannot be found or it is not installed properly..*

Does this have anything to do with the settings in the Data Source Admin settings? Am I missing a reference?

Here is all of the code if you are interested in seeing what all I have

```
Private Sub uploadBTN_Click()

'Dim adoCSVConnection, adoCSVRecordset, strPathToTextfile
'Dim strCSVFile, adoJetConnection, adoJetCommand, strDBPath

Dim adoCSVConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoCSVRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim adoJetConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoJetCommand As ADODB.Command

Set adoCSVConnection = New ADODB.Connection


Const adCmdText = &H1

' Specify path to CSV file. ex: c:\Scripts\
strPathToTextfile = "C:\Desktop\"

' Specify CSV file name. ex: Users.csv
strCSVFile = "testfile2.csv"

' Specify Access database file. ex: c:\Scripts\MyData.mdb
strDBPath = "\\folder\NewMasterclient.mdb"

' Open connection to the CSV file.
Set adoCSVConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoCSVRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Open CSV file with header line.
adoCSVConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strPathToTextfile & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""


adoCSVRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strCSVFile, adoCSVConnection

' Open connection to MS Access database.
Set adoJetConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoJetConnection.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);" _
    & "FIL=MS Access;DriverId=25;DBQ=" & strDBPath & ";"
adoJetConnection.Open

' ADO command object to insert rows into Access database.
Set adoJetCommand = New ADODB.Command
Set adoJetCommand.ActiveConnection = adoJetConnection
adoJetCommand.CommandType = adCmdText

' Read the CSV file.
Do Until adoCSVRecordset.EOF
    ' Insert a row into the Access database.
    adoJetCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testfile2" & "(a, b, c, d, clientid, reg) " & "VALUES (" _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("a").Value & "', " _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("b").Value & "', " _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("c").Value & "', " _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("d").Value & "', " _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("clientid").Value & "')" _
            & "'" & adoCSVRecordset.Fields("reg").Value & "')"

    adoJetCommand.Execute
    adoCSVRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

' Clean up.
adoCSVRecordset.Close
adoCSVConnection.Close
adoJetConnection.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using 64 bit Access?  `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` is only usable for 32 bit processes.

Comment: Darn.. I am.. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Yes.  See [DoCmd.TransferText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx).  That takes way less code than what you were trying to do.  :-)

Comment: Or if you want to stick with what you've got, use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will use this instead.. Time to rewrite everything! :)

Comment: I might be reaching.. but can you show me how I would need edit what I have to use TransferText? I've never seen that before.. the example on the link your provided should be straight forward right?

Comment: Start with this: `DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "testfile2", strPathToTextfile & strCSVFile, True`